# How to add button to the git toolbar in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a simple question. Google didn't help me. I work in Intellij IDEA, how can I add / remove buttons in [Git Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL11g.png)

Comment: What about the Jetbrains website?

Comment: @DamCx Sure! Before asking a question I've read everything I could find on this topic. To turn to the experience of others is the last thing.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html

Comment: @DamCx But there are over a hundred of a different VCS mentions at "Menus and Toolbars" tab. This is the reason of my question: maybe someone have a recent experience and knows exactly how to do it

Comment: But still, this is a very "broad" but also very specific question.

Comment: @GhostCat Very broad and very specific at the same time? Heisenquestion? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actions you need are under Main Toolbar | MainToolBarSettings | VCS Actions.

[image]

Comment: Exactly! That's where it's hidden what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Comment: It did not do anything on Idea 2021.3 macos